# android app with facebook SSO failure in release apk

Tags: android, facebook, publish, release-mode

I have a problem when I want to publish my android application with facebook integrated. I signed my app with eclipse, and used "keytool -exportcert -alias androidreleasekey -keystore MyReleaseKeystore.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64" in terminal to generate a release key, and I added in "Native Android App" configuration. If I try to log in fb via application I received dialog with nothing.

1. The path to keystore file is correct because keytool asked me for password.
2. I used the same keystore to sign apk in eclipse and to generate fb hash. Password is correct.
3. I copied generated hash to fb developer console.

When I tested with debugkey, all work fine. I had a problem with hash in debug mode but I could have turn on debugging in facebook sdk Util class and check in logcat the correct hash but in release apk this trick did not work (I could not see any error).

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check your alias in "-alias androidreleasekey" is the same with the alias you generated in ReleaseKeyStore.keystore